# doxygen doesnt seem to work well with class_exists-Method

Tags: php, doxygen

I want to use doxygen for document my PHP-Project (it's a Wordpress Plugin).
To be save, that I do not overwrite a existing class from any other Wordpress Plugin, I use the "class_exist"-Method.
But now, doxygen is only generate a documentation for my class, if i do any php call before my class definition.
An example:

```
/**
 * @author schmitt
 *
 * @file my_util_class.php
 *
 * @class my_util_class
 *
 * @brief small message
 *
 * big message
 */
 if ( ! class_exists( 'my_util_class' ) ) :
 //echo "hallo";
 class my_util_class
 {
    /**
     * @brief smalltest
     * bigtestmessage
     */
    public function test() {
        return "hallo";
    }

    //definition of other methods.
 }

 endif;
```

if i comment out the line *echo "hallo"* doxygen will generate a fully documentation of my class with all Methods.
But if the line is commented, only the header (defined with @file etc.) will documented well. None of the methods is going to be documented.

I have set the "Extract All" Parameter in the doxygen-Config to YES.
But this doesn't help.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Doxygen does not know about the class inside the if statement. Would a construct like if (class_exists( 'my_util_class' )) { return; } be feasible in your case as at that moment the class is visible in the documentation. As a side note it is not necessary to specify the file name wit the \file command when the documentation is in the same file (it is error prone).

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. When I try it, i become a strange result...When I do not encapsulate the class with "if (!class_exist ..." the Method class_exist everytime gives true. When I do the encapsulation, it gives everytime false. I don't understand why it is doing this. 
So:
$bool = class_exists('myClass');
class myClass ...
$bool = true

But:
$bool = class_exists('myClass');
if (class_exist('myClass')):
class myClass ...
endif;
$bool is false.
I don't know why.
$bool = true

Comment: I'm not a php specialist so cannot help you on this. This is probably something for another question more dedicated to the php / wordpress community.